# Beautiful Soup find_all() returns odd tags instead of results

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I'm using Beautiful Soup to get some information out of an XML file that looks like this:

```xml
<name>Ted</name>
<link>example.com/rss</link>
<link>example2.com/rss</link>
```

That is the entirety of the XML file that I am trying to read in at the moment, for test purposes.

When I try to use `find_all('link')` it returns a list that consists of this:

```
[ <link/>, <link/> ]
```

I can't seem to find any mention of something like this in any documentation, anyone able to tell me what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Including the code for parsing:

```
for file in glob.glob("*.xml"):
            if file.endswith(".xml"):
                    f = open(file, 'r');

                    #Reads in all information about the bot from the file
                    botFile = f.read()
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(botFile)

                    name = soup.find('name').get_text()

                    links = soup.find_all('link')
                    for link in links:
                            print link
```

Comment: How are you parsing said XML with BeautifulSoup? Please show us your code.

Comment: I've edited the original post to include the code. Retrieving the name from soup works just fine, if that helps.

Comment: Sidenote : I'm pretty sure the `file.endswith(".xml")` check is unnecessary.

Comment: As is the `f.read()` call; `soup = BeautifulSoup(f)` would also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parse XML with BeautifulSoup you need to use the *XML parser*; make sure you have [lxml installed](http://lxml.de/) and tell BeautifulSoup to use XML:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(document, 'xml')
```

otherwise the elements are parsed as [*HTML `<link>` tags*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link), which are empty by definition.

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> sample = '''\
... <root>
... <name>Ted</name>
... <link>example.com/rss</link>
... <link>example2.com/rss</link>
... </root>
... '''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(sample)
>>> soup.find_all('link')
[<link/>, <link/>]
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(sample, 'xml')
>>> soup.find_all('link')
[<link>example.com/rss</link>, <link>example2.com/rss</link>]
```

Note that without the second argument `'xml'` the results are empty tag objects, but with `'xml'` set the tag contents are there.

See [*Installing a parser*](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) and [*Parsing XML*](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#id17) in the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Beautiful Soup documentation mentions that it can't handle xml files properly. There is a module called BeautifulStoneSoup that handles xml files. It is a basic module and nothing fancy about it. However, if your file is a simple xml then it may very well do the job.
Here is the [link](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Parsing%20XML) to its documentation.

Comment: That's for BeautifulSoup version 3, which has been mothballed years ago. Version 4, used by the OP here, can handle XML just fine provided you use the right parser.